# Setting focus on first element of list item on HTML + Angular will focus the second one instead

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tabindex

I have been working on a requirement for an UI, as soon as the tab key is pressed for the first time, I need to set up the focus on the first element of a list item that is constructed with an array of objects. Next times I press tab key, I need to go over the list items and if I reach the end of the list, I go back to the first element.

Actually I achieved my goal partially, the problem I am facing is that as soon as I press the tab key for the first time, it focus the second list item instead of the first one and as soon as I reach the end of the list and I hit tab, it will focus the second one, it always skip the first list item, but not sure why.

This is the HTML code of the component:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="grandparent">
      <div class="parent">
        <ul #optionsTypeMenu>
          <li *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index; last as isLast" (click)="open(option)" tabindex="0" id="{{option.name}}">
            <div class="event-badge-block"
              [ngClass]="{ 'select': isSubmitted, 
                            'disabled': optionSelectionDisabled(option, isLast) }">
              <small class="bagde">{{ i + 1 }}</small>
              <div class="option-label">
                <span>{{ option.name}}
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code for the tab key:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.tab') focusOptionFindingsSection(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let activeElement = document.activeElement;
        let isCurrentFocusedElementTabable = this.optionsTypeMenu.nativeElement.contains(activeElement);

        if (!isCurrentFocusedElementTabable || this.CURR_TAB_INDEX == this.options.length - 1) {
            this.CURR_TAB_INDEX = 0;
        }

        if (this.CURR_TAB_INDEX == 0) {
            this.optionsTypeMenu.nativeElement.children[this.CURR_TAB_INDEX].focus();
        }

        this.CURR_TAB_INDEX++;
    }
```

I have been debugging and trying to force the focus with document.getElementById... but I got the same result. I was wondering if there is something I could have missed, not sure if tabindex could be the reason, but any clue or help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

As requested, I created a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-and-display-in-ul-and-li-hbg7xj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: yes, sure, I updated the post with the following URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-and-display-in-ul-and-li-hbg7xj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Amenawon is right in the fact that the issue here is that you are triggering focus event twice.

Once from `this.optionsTypeMenu.nativeElement.children[0].focus();` and the second being the default event from the `tab` key.

To do this properly prevent this in angular we need to specify what key to listen to, and what arguments to pass to the listener

like so `@HostListener('document:keydown.tab', ['$event'])`

That's why your event argument was undefined

see full fix here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-and-display-in-ul-and-li-iay5m3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

It could be the Browsers default behaviour, try adding an `event.preventDefault()` statement before setting the active element

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, it is not working, event comes as undefined, I added a condition there to call preventDefault only when event has a value, but it does not make any change :(

Comment: When the page is loaded, what is the value of current tab index. Also can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: for sure, I've just did it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-and-display-in-ul-and-li-hbg7xj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts